# Spring - The requested resource is not available

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to build a basic Java app with Spring MVC, however, I am having troubles with links within the app.

Here is my `web.xml`

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/test-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/welcome.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/welcome.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My `test-servlet.xml`

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.springtest.controller"/>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">

    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>./WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp </value>
    </property>

</bean>
```

The first page that gets displayed when running the app is the following:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring MVC Tutorial</title>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<div style="text-align:center">
    <h3>
        <a href="welcome">Click to say hello </a>
    </h3>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And welcome.jsp is this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World MVC</title>

</head>
<body>${message}

</body>
</html>
```

Since this is my first time using Spring (and I know there are a lot of questions here asking/answering this - thus I haven't been able to find an answer that helps me), I followed an [online tutorial](http://crunchify.com/simplest-spring-mvc-hello-world-example-tutorial-spring-model-view-controller-tips/).

My folder structer is similar to what they have in the tutorial, however, every time I click the link to go to the second page, I get a 404 Error saying that:

```
/SpringTutorial-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/jsp/welcome.jsp - is not available
```

Comment: <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Basically `/` in the `<url-pattern>` tag is enough.It will take of `/welcome.jsp` or `/welcome.html`.

   ```
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   ```
2. No need to give relative path in `value` property of `prefix`.

   ```
   <property name="prefix">
       <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
   </property>
   ```

And one more thing is you can also try with `InternalResourceViewResolver` in place of `UrlBasedViewResolver`.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp" />  
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />  
</bean>
```

Comment: I still get the same error. Can the error occur because of a read access of the file welcome.jsp after it's being deployed to Tomcat?

Comment: Can you show the directory structure and also controller

Comment: @AdrianDanielCulea change anchor tag to  this to `<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/welcome">Click to say hello </a>` and viewResolver to InternalResourceViewResolver

Comment: Issue resolved. I have identified a bug in my code. The change of the Resolver fixed my initial issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change your form action to welcome.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring MVC Tutorial</title>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<div style="text-align:center">
    <h3>
        <a href="welcome.html">Click to say hello </a>
    </h3>
</div>
</body>
</html>

also change url pattern to / or *.html


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/test-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

also view resolver to internal resource view resolver and avoid giving relative url in it.
```

Also make sure that you have given @controller annotation.
And URL mapping as 
@requestmapping("/welcome")